# How Docker Images Works when Code is Re-deployed ? does existing Image deleted and re-created again

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Might be this question is very basic and even not proper but I am new to the docker and I read somewhere the docker image is read-only that is once it created then can not be modified or changed but we can delete, then what's happen when is re-deployed the same code again does it creates the new image by deleting existing image or every time it will create the new image?.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Docker Images are created newly everytime you redeploy(docker build) if there are any changes from your previous version code. You can understand it by tracking the image id it creates. If there are no changes from the previous version of the code. Then the image stays the same no matter how many times you redeploy(docker build) unless you delete it.